# Nodejs mixed async functions and promises

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, sails.js, waterline

So I have sails app with some help service to make it easier to create and get complex models.
one of theses are

```
getMerits: function(profileId, limit){
return async.waterfall([
  function(callback){
    Merit.find({employeeProfile: profileId}).then(function(merits){
      callback(null, merits);
    });
  },
  function(merits, callback){
    async.forEach(merits, function(item, loop_callback){
      MeritIndex.findOne({id: item.index}).then(function(meritIndex){
        merits[merits.indexOf(item)].index = meritIndex;
        loop_callback();
      });
    }, function(err, results){
      callback(null, merits);
  });
  }
], function(err, results){
  return results;
});
```

}

the trouble is when I try to call this function to get the result(list of merits with their meritindexes inserted.) I cant figure out the correct way to get the results returned from the async waterfall:

```
async.forEach(profiles, function(item, loop_callback){
      MeritService.getMerits(item.id, 5).exec(function(err, merits){
        console.log(merits)
        profiles[profiles.indexOf(item)].merits = merits;
        loop_callback();
      });
      // MeritService.getMerits(item.id, 5).exec(function(m){
      //   console.log(m)
      //   profiles[profiles.indexOf(item)].merits = m;
      //   loop_callback();
      // });
    }, function(err){
        console.log("PROFILES" + JSON.stringify(profiles))
    });
```

the print  of merits here results in undefined. Is there any way to treat async waterfall as a promise and use then instead of exec?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `async.waterfall` since you already have promises, promises chain already - so adding another library for that logic is redundant. Waterline uses bluebird promises  which come with convenience methods already.

Your getMerits can be written as:

```
getMerits: function(profileId, limit){
  var merits = Merit.find({employeeProfile: profileId}); 
  var items = merits.map(function(item) {
    return MeritIndex.findOne({id: item.index }).then(function(meritIndex) {
      item.index = meritIndex;
    });
  });
  return items.return(merits); // wait for items to be done, and return the merits
}
```

P.S.
If you use Node 4+ let me know since it gets even simpler.

Comment: I'm curious about this simpler usage in node 4+

Comment: Thank you, that looks way better. I'm curious how node 4 could do this better, and also. What is the correct way to use the getMerits function? As someone used to python I find this extremely confusing. If I try to put the return value in a variable it results in null, and if i try to use it as before it says `Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined`

Comment: And the line `var items = merits.map(function(item) {` gives the error `Unhandled rejection TypeError: undefined is not a function
`